Deploying a Google function using .NET/C# in Visual Studio giving an error after a deployment command
I am following this guide on deploying a .NET Google Cloud Platform function exactly: Create and deploy an HTTP Cloud Function with .NET
I get to the stage of executing this command:
gcloud functions deploy csharp-http-function --gen2 --entry-point=HelloWorld.Function --runtime=dotnet6 --region=us-central1 --source=. --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated

And I am getting this error:

ERROR: gcloud crashed (PermissionError): [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.\.vs\helloworld\FileContentIndex\030dc1d0-8d66-48c0-a87a-6905f4a624ae.vsidx'

Most of the solutions I see for this problem are that this error occurs when trying to access a directory instead of a file, but that is very clearly a file at the end of the command with a .vsidx extension
I don't have any idea why this is happening and it is really stumping me.
I have a helloworld directory, with the HelloWorld.csproj and Function.cs files inside, nothing else. I have executed the gcloud authorization command within the PowerShell window and connected my account and linked up with the appropriate project.

I've found this recently, deploying from an entirely separate command line window, but with VS open - although it didn't happen in the past. (I don't know if that's a VS change or a gcloud change.)
The simplest way to avoid this is to create a .gcloudignore file - mine typically looks like this:
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore
.vs
bin
obj


Well, I feel silly. This was happening because I was trying to run the deploy command from within my Visual Studio PowerShell Window, meaning the file was open and locked, making it inaccessible.

Create a .gcloudignore file so that those types of files/directories are not uploaded as they are not used and will increase your costs.
